# How do I set the src to an iframe with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, src

My iFrame looks like this:

```
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe1" frameborder="0" src=""></iframe>
```

And my script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#iframe').attr('src',http://google.com);
})
</script>
```

I've also tried putting quotes around the url:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#iframe').attr('src','http://google.com');
})
</script>
```

But neither is working.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting any errors from the browser?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/8JKxh/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you look at the browser's error console, you'll see the real problem:

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Google doesn't let you do that.

Comment: This is the right answer. It works when used with another URL. I tried disney.com and it worked fine (once height/width attributes were added).

Comment: @SLaks - Is that from google's meta tag: `<meta id="mref" name="referrer" content="origin">`?

Comment: Yes, Firefox is giving me a similar error:
`Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.`
Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/7vuB4/

Comment: @TravisJ: No; it's due to the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 9):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#iframe').attr('src', 'http://google.com');
})
</script>
```

Quotes missing on the url.

Comment: Hey, sorry I just edited it to include that. That isn't working either.

Comment: Do you have the full code? And is your browser giving you an error?

Answer (score 4):

You're not allowed to load www.google.com in an iFrame. Try it with another url.

`Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.`

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#iframe").attr("src","your url");
```

this will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the function with Iframe name and desired url

```
function loadIframe(iframeName, url) {
    var $iframe = $('#' + iframeName);
    if ( $iframe.length ) {
        $iframe.attr('src',url);   
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Ex:

```
loadIframe("iframe1","http://yahoo.com");
```